# List has 2 elements but iterator returns only 1 element

Tags: list, c++11, iterator

I am implementing graph and I added vertexes 0,1,2. Edges looks like this 0-1, 0-2.
Problem is i want to iterate throw all neighbours of all vertexes. Code bellow returns number of neighbours for each vertex. It returns correct number but for vertex 0 it only goes throw one iteration even thow GetNeighbours.size() for vertex0 returns 2. Any help?

```
// Main.cpp
std::list<Vertex> l = graph->GetAllVertexes();
std::list<Vertex> l2; // ---- IT WORKED AFTER THIS
std::list<Vertex>::iterator it2;
std::list<Vertex>::iterator it3;
for (it2 = l.begin(); it2 != l.end(); ++it2)
{
    cout << "Vertex: " << it2->GetId() << "\n";
    cout << "Number of neighbours: " << it2->GetNeighbours().size() << "\n";
    l2 = it2 ->GetNeighbours();                    // ---- IT WORKED AFTER THIS
    for (it3 = l2.begin(); it3 != l2.end(); ++it3) // ---- IT WORKED AFTER THIS
    {
        //cout << "iteration\n";
        cout << it3->GetId() << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
--------------------------------------------------
// Vertex.cpp
#include "Vertex.h" 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

Vertex::Vertex(){}
Vertex::~Vertex(){}

Vertex::Vertex(long _id)
{
    id = _id;
}

Vertex::Vertex(long _id, string _data) 
{
    id = _id;
    data = _data;
}

long Vertex::GetId()
{
    return id;
}

string Vertex::GetData()
{
    return data;
}

void Vertex::AddNeighbourVertex(Vertex *vertex)
{
    std::list<Vertex>::iterator it;
    for (it = neighbours.begin(); it != neighbours.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (it->GetId() == vertex->GetId()) return;
    }
    neighbours.push_back(*vertex);
}

list<Vertex> Vertex::GetNeighbours()
{
    return neighbours;
}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is most likely not in the code you show, but in the code you *don't* show us (more specifically how you set up all your vertexes and link them together). Please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Thanks it worked after I coppied it2 -> GetNeighbours() to another list and iterated throw that new list!

Answer (score 0):

`neighbours` can't be a `list` of `Vertex`, try making it a `list` of `Vertex*`

This is due to value semantics, when you copy a neighbour into the list
its neighbours gets copied too.

For an example of how it could work, see http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ef4b53212d76607